# Remove single quote character from string using thymeleaf

Tags: thymeleaf

I am new to thymeleaf and recently I am trying to figure out how to remove special characters from a string. Following (text in bold) code is working for me except 'single quote' :

{ #strings.toLowerCase(#strings.replace(#strings.replace(#strings.replace(name, 
   '\'' ,'-'), '&',''),' ','-'))}

I tried using &apos and \' but not working. I went through [thymeleaf preprocessing](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#preprocessing) but couldn't get any help from it. Is there any way around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
${#strings.toLowerCase(#strings.replace(#strings.replace(#strings.replace(name, '''','-'), '&',''),' ','-'))}
```

Comment: Working !! Thank you so much !!